# ¿Cómo obtener valor especifico de un Json Array en SqlServer?

Tags: sql-server, json, jsonobject, jsonarray

¿Cómo puedo recorrer el objeto y obtener los valores específicos del json?

Este es el formato:

```
[{"NumberId":"123456789-0","CompanyName":"Team Leader","IdKey":"1867","Industry":"Home Supplies, Garden & Construction Materials"},
 {"NumberId":"123456789-0","CompanyName":"Team Leader","IdKey":"301782","Industry":"Business and Professional Services, Distribution lists"},
 {"NumberId":"123456789-0","CompanyName":"Team Leader","IdKey":"1875","Industry":"Indumentaria, Textiles y Accesorios"}]
```

Estoy usando este código, pero no me establece los valores en la variable @CompanyName (Me devuelve null).

```
 DECLARE @itemsJson VARCHAR(MAX) = (SELECT NumberId, CompanyName,[Key] AS IdKey, [Value] AS Industry FROM CompanyProfile  CROSS APPLY OpenJson(IndustryMainSector) WITH ([Key] varchar(10), [Value] varchar(1000)) FOR JSON AUTO);
              DECLARE @index INT = 0;
                          DECLARE @Cçcontador INT = 3;
              SELECT @itemsJson
              DECLARE @companyName VARCHAR(200);

              WHILE(@index < @contador)
                 BEGIN
        
                     SET @id = @index + 1 ;
                     SET @companyName = CONCAT('$.CompanyName[', @index ,']');
                     SET @companyName = (JSON_VALUE(@itemsJson, @companyName));
                     SELECT @companyname
                     SET @index = @index + 1;

                 END
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema es que tienes el índice en el lugar incorrecto.

```
SET @companyName = CONCAT('$[', @index ,'].CompanyName');
```

También podrías tener todo en un solo resultado usando una tabla de números.

```
 DECLARE @itemsJson VARCHAR(MAX) = '[{"NumberId":"123456789-0","CompanyName":"Team Leader","IdKey":"1867","Industry":"Home Supplies, Garden & Construction Materials"},
 {"NumberId":"123456789-0","CompanyName":"Team Leader","IdKey":"301782","Industry":"Business and Professional Services, Distribution lists"},
 {"NumberId":"123456789-0","CompanyName":"Team Leader","IdKey":"1875","Industry":"Indumentaria, Textiles y Accesorios"}]';

WITH 
E(n) AS(
    SELECT n FROM (VALUES(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0))E(n)
),
E2(n) AS(
    SELECT a.n FROM E a, E b
),
E4(n) AS(
    SELECT a.n FROM E2 a, E2 b
),
cteTally(n) AS(
    SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) - 1 n
    FROM E4
)
SELECT JSON_VALUE(@itemsJson, cp.companyPath)
FROM cteTally
CROSS APPLY( SELECT CONCAT('$[', n ,'].CompanyName') AS companyPath) cp
WHERE n < 3;
```